# Show view in Drupal based off of Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have been asked a favor of a friend who uses drupal to help them implement a way that they can easily upload an excel document and have it draw out certain fields of the data on a different page in paragraphs and headers.. I have experience in Python, ASP.NET, and PHP but have never used drupal and know nothing about it. If i was given the task in those languages it would be very simple for me but since I know absolutely nothing about Drupal I was curious if someone could just explain to me how this could be done in Drupal so that i could then research and implement at the same time.

Thank you and I appreciate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

First I would create a content type with the suitable fields to contain the data, and a 'file' field to allow the upload of the excel spreadsheet.

Then in a [custom module](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7) I would use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a secondary submit handler (that runs before the main one) to the node add form, and in the new submit handler would parse the spreadsheet and populate the other node fields.
Then after this Drupals main submit handler will run and create the node with your values.

Once you have a node with the data you want it in take a look at the [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module for an easy way to output / display the data. Views can create blocks and blocks can easily be inserted into any region in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

Another Way might be the feeds module. There is also an excel parser https://drupal.org/project/feeds_excel , though I only used csv imports.

1. You set up a content type with the appropriate fields for the each of the columns in your spreadsheet you want to import.
2. you configure feeds to import them into that specific content type

I hope it helps somewhat.

Comment: I'd not heard of that module before but it sounds like it could be ideal for this...